# monaca.getDeviceIdで取得できるデバイスIDの永続性について

Tags: monaca

アカウントと紐付けるための情報として、表題のデバイスIDを利用しようかと思っていますが、
それに関連して下記の質問があります。

- **デバイスIDの変更のタイミング**
  マニュアルには「アプリの初回起動時に、一意のデバイス ID を、自動的に生成します。」とありますが、アプリを再インストールしたときには変更されるのでしょうか。
  その他、変更されるタイミングをご存じであれば教えていただけないでしょうか。
- **デバイスIDの代替となるID情報**
  デバイスIDの代わりになるようなID情報として何か考えられるものはありますでしょうか。
  ただし、ユーザが自分でアカウント情報を入力することは考えておらず、自動生成可能なものが望ましいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tarouさん

先日、実機テストを何回か行っていた時の私が確認出来た事に関しまして、
共有させて頂きます。

iOS: iPhone6(iOS 9.1) 
Android: SC-02C (Android 4.0.3)
で確認しました。

まず、 iOSでもAndroid であっても、
アプリを終了させて、再度、アプリを立ち上げる。
といった動作の場合は、端末IDは同じでした。

ただ、iOS側にて、一度インストールしたアプリを、
アンインストールして、再度アプリをインストールした後に
立ち上げると、端末IDは変わりました。

Androidは、一度アンインストールして、
再度、インストールし直しても、変わらなかったので、
もしかしたら、OS単位で生成の仕様が異なっているのだと思います。

2に関しては、
メールアドレスや電話番号が一般的かと思いますが、それが無理であれば、
[MonacaのユーザーAPI](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/monaca_api/cloud/user/) を使用されるのがよろしいかと思います。

流れとしては、
１． アプリ起動時に、WebAPI等で一意のIDを取得する。
２． Monaca側でそれをMonacaバックエンドのユーザーAPIに渡して、
　　 ユーザー情報を作成する。（次回移行は自動ログインとする）
３． Monacaから、ユーザー登録完了メールを送る。
　　（もし、アプリをアンインストールされた場合は、一意のIDを再度入力して貰って、
　　　再度、紐付けを行って頂く。）
ような感じでしょうか。

私も詳しい方ではありませんが。。。特にiOS側では、一意の端末のIDを取るのは難しい、という認識です。

もっといい方法があるかもしれないですが、その辺りは、知識不足でお力になれそうにないです。

Comment: ご丁寧に調べて下さいましてありがとうございます。
やはりmonacaの枠組みの中で、永続的なIDを取得することは難しそうですね。

ID情報をユーザが管理することは避けたかったので、
同一端末であれば、毎回同じIDが生成できる仕組みがあれば良かったのですが・・・。

IDの紐付けを手動でやる場合、記入くださっている手順が現実的ですね。
参考にさせていただきます。